# How can I compare the growth rates of (3/2)^n and (log n)^(log n)?(Log to the base 2).I tried limit test, L'Hospital's rule, but to no avail

Tags: performance, algorithm, time-complexity

I'm trying to compare the growth rates of (3/2)^n and (log n) ^ (log n). But I'm not sure what method gives me any clue towards that!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.  Try math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take log of both.

```
1. log((3/2)^n) = n * log 3/2
2. log(log n ^ log n) = log log n * log n
```

(1) grows faster than (2).

To show that, it is sufficient to show `n` grows faster than even `(log n)^2`.

---

Between n and (log n)^2, taking log -

```
3. log n
4. 2 log log n
```

(3) grows faster than (4). [Well, in fact, this also shows `n` grows faster than any power of `log n`.]

---

So putting it together,

`log n` grows faster than `2 log log n`

=> `n` grows faster than `log n * log n`

=> `n log(3/2)` grows faster than `log log n * log n`

=> `(3/2)^n` grows faster than `log n ^ log n`

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you take the log of both sides you get log(3/2^n) and log(log(n)^log(n)).  For large values of n, if one grows faster, its log grows faster.

This yields n * log(3/2) and  log(n)*(log(log(n))

At this point, I would eyeball it, but to go further, log(log(n)) grows slower than log(n) so if n*log(3/2) grows faster than log(n)*log(n), it also grows faster than log(n)*log(log(n).

Dropping the constant, we have to see if n grows faster log(n)*log(n).  The right hand side can become log(n)^2, so we can instead see if sqrt(n) grows faster than log(n).  That proof is trivial.

Since sqrt(n) is faster than log(n), n*log(3/2) is faster than log(n)^2, which means n is also faster than log(n)*log(log(n)), which means log(3/2^n) grows fatsserthan log(n)^(log(n))

Comment: Okay, but how exactly is square root faster than log? I know it's true, but can't prove it trivially! It doesn't appear to be "that" obvious.

Comment: Ok, I could prove it.